# Disqus API listPosts doesn't include links back to the original page

Tags: hyperlink, comments, disqus

I am using this API http://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/listPosts/ to get the list of recent comments, but the result from the API doesn't include the links for the content page on my site. I have tried find it in the API pages and no luck. Just curious if anyone knows how to get these links.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the console a bit more, found out that in order to get this information, I need to pass "related=thread" in the api param.